# Returning AJAX results for multiple items

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pull each ID of every item of a particular class, pass it to a php script to process, then return the results to the item itself. Seems to be working for the most part, but I am getting the same random number back for each item.

Here's the jQuery

```
function loadRenew()
{
    $('.renewItem').each(function(){

         var currentItem = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

         //$('#loading').css('visibility','visible');   //show the rotating gif animation

         $.ajax({   //create an ajax request
                type: "POST",
                url: "renew.php",
                data: 'barcode='+currentItem,   //with the page number as a parameter
                dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
                success: function(msg){

                    if(parseInt(msg)!=0)    //if no errors
                    {
                        $("#"+currentItem).html(msg);   //load the returned html
                        //$('#loading').css('visibility','hidden'); //and hide the rotating gif
                    }
                }

            });

    });
}
```

and the PHP

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['barcode']) die("0");

$barcode = (int)$_POST['barcode'];

echo 'barcode returned is: ' . $barcode;

?>
```

I'm not getting the current barcode (currentItem) back, but the same random number in each div.

Example processed results:

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="libcard_title"><b>Title: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;">     Politics and cinema / Andrew Sarris. <span style="font-weight:     bold;">PN1995.9.P6&nbsp;S2</span> Stacks</span></div>
   <div class="card_info">
      <b>Checked Out: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 02/05/2014</span> \
      <p><b>Date Due: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 05/16/2014</span></p>
      <div class="renewItem" id="30291002497476">barcode returned is: 2147483647</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
   <div class="libcard_title"><b>Title: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> The         statics of particles and rigid bodies. <span style="font-weight:     bold;">QA821&nbsp;.H47</span> Stacks</span></div>
   <div class="card_info">
      <b>Checked Out: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 02/06/2014</span>
      <p><b>Date Due: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 05/17/2014</span></p>
      <div class="renewItem" id="30291003147765">barcode returned is: 2147483647</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
   <div class="libcard_title"><b>Title: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;">     Tablets <span style="font-weight: bold;"></span> Reserve</span></div>
   <div class="card_info">
      <b>Checked Out: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 02/18/2014</span>
      <p><b>Date Due: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 02/21/2014</span></p>
      <p><b>Fine: <span style="font-family: Courier; color:red;"> $5.00</span></b></p>
      <div class="renewItem" id="30291009878660">barcode returned is: 2147483647</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
   <div class="libcard_title"><b>Title: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> Dog    day afternoon [videorecording] / Warner Bros Pictures ; an Artists Entertainment Complex    product <span style="font-weight: bold;">PN1997&nbsp;.D63 2006</span> Media DVD</span>       </div>
   <div class="card_info">
      <b>Checked Out: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 02/05/2014</span>
      <p><b>Date Due: </b> <span style="font-family: Courier;"> 02/12/2014</span></p>
      <div class="renewItem" id="30291010328143">barcode returned is: 2147483647</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What random number are you getting, and what is an example of `currentItem`?

Comment: Remove (int) from the $barcode = ... line in PHP and echo only $barcode. Not sure if this is exactly the error cause of the error but those are unnecessary for sure.

Comment: there is an issue, beforesend is a function but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: When I have problems with AJAX requests here's what I do. Open the browser's developer tools and go to the Network tab. Create the AJAX request, then watch it come across the Network tab. Look at the parameters being sent with the request, then look at the request's response. This shows you everything you need to know to determine where the issue exists. Was the parameter sent incorrectly? Then check your JS. Was the input correct but the output not correct? Then check your PHP. I'll throw this out there too, technically, in the HTML 4 spec, IDs should not start with a number.

Comment: @Dutchie432 I added the results.

Comment: If I pass another variable i.e. data: 'barcode='+someotherNum, and say increment it for each, it returns the correct number. Just baffled why it's not passing or returning the number I need.

Comment: @Charles380 before send was there accidentally, not in my actual code.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for the tip. It looks like it is posting the correct data, but not returning it. I have no idea why this is though. If I pass it anything other than currentItem, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is no random number. The number 2,147,483,647 is also the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer in computing. It is therefore the maximum value for variables declared as "int".

Try using strings instead. Don't parse it as an int value, that should do the trick.

Comment: Solved! Removed (int) from $barcode in the PHP. Works like a charm. Thanks Kyle and @lucasnadalutti!